# Counting unique values in Range which is Index by another Value

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, count

I have a list of urgency types which are sorted by building name and Community. Every building name has 5 urgency types and each community has a varying number of buildings in it. I am trying to return a count of how many buildings are associated to each community.

I have tried this formula

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(BuildingCostsTbl[Building Name - Click to go to Sheet],BuildingCostsTbl[Building Name - Click to go to Sheet]&""))
```

but it only returns the total number of buildings in the table and does not count by community. I have also tried using the MATCH function within this to narrow the range criteria for the COUNTIF function but i keep getting errors I do not understand.

Here is an snapshot from my excel worksheet of what I am looking to do.

Excel Snapshot

[image]

The MATCH formula I was trying to use to narrow the COUNTIF lookup range is

```
=MATCH(H9,BuildingCostsTbl[Community])
```

Comment: Simplest method of doing that would be a `Pivot Table`.  If you select `Add to Data Model`, **Distinct Count** will be one of the options.  And you can use the Pivot table to also `Sum` the costs for each Community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a small example based on [this](https://exceljet.net/formula/count-unique-text-values-with-criteria) handy source:

[image]

The formula with above sample data in `D2`:

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF($A$2:$A$9=C2,MATCH($B$2:$B$9,$B$2:$B$9,0)),ROW($B$2:$B$9)-1)>0))
```

> ***Note:*** It's an array formula and need to be confirmed through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

You can adapt this to your needs when you use your table.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I tried your formula and adapted it and everything works except for in the No. of Buildings column for Aroland, The formula should output 2 but it is only giving a value of 1. Here is a link for a screenshot showing the exact formula and referencing. https://imgur.com/a/rJanc3F

Comment: @Marmiketin, you need to enter this formula as array as explained in the answer. Please try to do so.

Comment: yes i did that and in the formula bar it shows it with the squiggly brackets at both ends like this {=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(BuildingCostsTbl[Community]=H9,MATCH(BuildingCostsTbl[Building Name],BuildingCostsTbl[Building Name],0)),ROW(BuildingCostsTbl[Building Name])-1)>0))} but still will not count 2 buildings under Aroland. I have done this same thing using a Pivot Table and it does count 2 for Aroland.

Comment: Ah right, @Marmiketin, in your case you start the formula at row 9 so you need to minus 8 instead of 1. That will work ;)

Comment: Awesome that worked, I was wondering what that -1 was for. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Pivot Table.

Given this data:

[image]

`Insert Pivot Table` and select `add this data to the Data Model`

[image]

Drag

- Community to Rows
- Building Name to Values
- Costs to Values

Edit the Value Field Settings for Building Name:

- Distinct Count
- Change the column name

Edit the column name for the Costs column

Voila:

[image]

Comment: Yes a pivot table would be simplest, forgot about it for a second :S

Comment: @JvdV Depends on how dynamic the OP requires the sheet to be.  It is simpler, but if you update the data, you need to update the Pivot Table.